# How to make Apache Tomcat Server Accissible via IP address in windows server

Tags: tomcat, windows-server

I am new to server area. I never used Windows server before. I have public IP and connected to the server. Currently, I have IIS in server which is accessible from internet (http://103.69.125.162) . Now, I need to deploy a JAVA Web App. To do so I installed Tomcat and Postgresql. Tomcat is accessible tonlocal ip address or localhost:8080 but not accessible to http://103.69.125.162:8080. What should I do to make it accessible to public IP address.

Currently installed tomcat version is 8.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `address` attribute of  the `<Connector..../>` of **server.xml**

1. Edit tomcat/conf/server.xml.
2. Specify a bind address for that connector:

   `<Connector  port="8080"  protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="Public IP"   connectionTimeout="20000"  redirectPort="8443"  />`

Comment: server login is not available out of office ... i will check and provide response to you ... thanks for reply ..

Comment: You can also specify 0.0.0.0 as address , in which tomcat bind with all IP's . (e.g) `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" />`

Comment: Also check your firewall settings , which may prevent to access the tomcat by using public ip.

Comment: It didnot work .. I unlock the port form firewall... with recommended changes in server.xml file

Comment: I am able to ping your IP - 103.69.125.162 from my network. Is the port 8080 is opened from firewall? Also run the `netstat - an | find "8080"` in the command window and verify 8080 is bind with your IP or not.

Comment: Seems that you want IIS + Tomcat , in which IIS acts as a load balancer or webserver & Tomcat is the real request processor. You can follow https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/tomcat-tcat-server/load-balancing-tomcat-7-using-iis-7-5/  & https://infocenter.informationbuilders.com/wf80/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpubdocs%2FInstalls%2FDevStudio%2Fsource%2Ftopic21.htm &https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html